# Upgrade to geth 1.10.18 with brew not working

Tags: go-ethereum, brew

I’m trying to upgrade geth 1.10.17 to 1.10.18 using brew, but it keeps reinstalling 1.10.17
I’m using :

```
brew update && brew upgrade && brew reinstall ethereum
```

And get this:

Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
fastlane                                                    fplll
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/ethereum/manifests/1.10.17
Already downloaded: /Users/sergi/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/3d10d480b45a0568659167b74b25e38ccba481482e2b12b4dd273f4a2476464d--ethereum-1.10.17.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/ethereum/blobs/sha256:64b0aa19ed69711f55f819ee135caae41515e32abc3f36a
Already downloaded: /Users/sergi/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/ce117d0129a59ccb77ffc3c3fa477cd41bccce7beddb87dc7c3306baa1b8384e--ethereum--1.10.17.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Reinstalling ethereum
==> Pouring ethereum--1.10.17.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/ethereum/1.10.17: 19 files, 185.6MB
==> Running `brew cleanup ethereum`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).

How can I update geth to the latest release?

Comment: No error? What's the issue?

Comment: No errors, brew downloads 1.10.17 and reinstalls it

Comment: I see now that the latest version available through brew is still 1.10.17 https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ethereum

Answer (score 0):

The latest verion of ethereum on brew is 1.10.17, you can see that using `brew info ethereum` -

```
ethereum: stable 1.10.17 (bottled), HEAD
Official Go implementation of the Ethereum protocol
https://geth.ethereum.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/ethereum.rb
License: LGPL-3.0-or-later
==> Dependencies
Build: go ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 2,303 (30 days), 8,208 (90 days), 36,241 (365 days)
install-on-request: 2,302 (30 days), 8,202 (90 days), 36,220 (365 days)
build-error: 5 (30 days)
```

It takes someone to update the formula before it's reflected on Homebrew.